# Adjectives describing quantity

Tags: adjectives, compound-adjectives, deverbal-adjectives, predicate-adjectives, attributive-adjectives

What is the difference between **indefinite adjectives** and **adjectives of quantity**.

Are **indefinite adjectives** and **adjectives of quantity** are same.

Comment: Hello, 372. Please be aware that reading terms like 'indefinite adjectives' in some book / article on grammar does not guarantee (a) that the term is in general use, (b) that the use of the term is even helpful, or (c) that all Anglophones will understand how the term is intended to be used by the authors. Also, on occasion, different authors use the same term with conflicting meanings. It is necessary to give a suitable quote,  linked and attributed, for each term. // I'd say that 'adjectives of quantity' is probably a term rejected by modern grammarians, who consider 'many', 'all' etc ...

Comment: to be members of a totally different word class, determiners/determinatives (subclass quantifiers). 'Indefinite adjectives' seems to be another misnomer for quantifiers. See, for instance, [Grammar Monster](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/indefinite_adjectives.htm).

Comment: Please provide at least one or two example sentences that demonstrate what you are thinking those terms apply to.

Comment: 1.He has much wealth

Comment: He has many  cars.    In the above 2 examples much and many are indefinite adjectives or adjectives of quantity.